# Axle spline on AWD damage

Tags: ford, awd, cv-joint, edge

I went to replace a wheel bearing and noticed damage on the spline. The nut spun off fine, but I’m not sure if I should replace whole cv axle as well due to this. 2009 AWD FORD EDGE

[image]

Comment: Any chance that the CV unit isn't original? Perhaps the previous owner replaced it with some "it fits, somehow" unit? And had, judging from the picture, only a large hammer and anger issues?

Comment: Is the nut removed in that photo?

Comment: The nut did come of with the assistant of steady pressure on the backside from a small pry bar. It appears to be original CV joint. The wheel and hub on the other hand have definitely been replaced by likely a junkyard replacement part. I’m guessing that’s where the damage occurred. Someone getting way too aggressive trying to push the axle out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would replace the entire unit. The reason being it is highly unlikely you will be able to get the nut to start correctly. The nut will wind up cross-threading and won't torque correctly. As a side note there is a reason almost all manufacturers design the axle end with a longer threaded section. I don't know what the reason is, but they don't add extra material and cost unless it is needed.

Comment: Sometimes they reuse existing models, while it increases material costs it eases logistics. I, personally, would cut it..

Comment: Going to try this. Angle grinder and cutting wheel for the cut?